# How to achive the importance of each variable for SVM after classification?

Tags: svm, libsvm

I have two classes and several variables. After training the SVM, it gives me a good accuracy on prediction of testing data classes. Does anybody know how can I find out which of my variables are less important in the prediction done by SVM ? I'm nearly new in SVM and I'm just familiar with console interface and matlab interface of SVM. Is there any option to achive the importance of variables for SVM after training or prediction phase ?

Comment: Please ask your question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What you want to achieve is an estimation of "feature importance". use Google with these keywords.

Comment: I had searched for this before, but as I find, there is nothing such as "feature importance". there are some indirect methods like F-score, Random Forest and so on ...

Comment: @Wok I just want to know if there is anyway to find out after building the model file by SVM, is it possible to know what weight is given to each feature?! ... Just SVM, not overall methods or other classifiers.

Comment: If you use penalized linear SVM, then yes.

Comment: Yes! I use linear kernel of SVM, but if you mean "w" values of "wx+b" which is the normal vector of each plan, I didn't understand what does it really says to me.

Comment: This question really belongs to http://stats.stackexchange.com/